# One Hot Encoding - how to fix columns matching in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding

I am facing some issue in Logistic Regression with one hot encoding.

This is my scenario.

I have train data with a Categorical feature and encoded using one hot encoding.

```
   Limit        Color       Output (Predicted Output)
   4            Red         1
   2            Blue        0
   6            Yellow      1
```

And after using one hot encoding for the color feature I have 2 additional  features (as expected)  like

```
Limit       Color_Red   Color_Blue  Color_Yellow    Output
4               1           0            0            1
2               0           1            0            0 
6               0           0            1            1
```

And I have created the model and evaluated and scored using Logistic Regression and it is working fine as expected.

Now I want to predict user input data and with below structure.

```
Limit       Color   
6           Red
```

And converted one hot encoding for color feature and i got this structure.

```
Limit       Color_Red   
6             1
```

And When I called modle.predict function by passing this input data i got below error ..

`X has 2 features per sample; expecting 4` 
And of course, input data features count is not matching with model input features count.

How to fix it and appreciated your help.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: How are you doing your OHE? Are you using a pandas get_dummies, an sklearn onehotencoder that you called 'fit' on? An sklearn labelencoder?

Comment: I am using pandas get_dummies.

Comment: I resume you need to give it a column entry of zero for blue and yellow

Comment: Yes, but not manually. Sometimes we can expect color value is Blue and we have to create columns for Red and Yellow and set value as 0.

Comment: You need to define a function to take in the unencoded data and reformat it into an array of the correct shape. For example, `out_array=[0,0,0];if color='red': out_array[1]=1` or something of that nature

Comment: it means we cannot use panda get_dummies function().

Comment: I would suggest you to try to read this [Example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py).